# how to fix groupby elimination of index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Please see images -

[image]
[image]

After creating a dataframe, I use groupby, then I reset the index column only to find that the column for 'county' is still unseen by the dataframe. Please help to rectify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `df.reset_index()` by default is not an "inplace" operation. But with use of the `inplace` parameter you can make it behave as such.

##### 1. Either use `inplace=True` -

```
mydf.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

##### 2. Or save the `df` into another (or the same) variable -

```
mydf = mydf.reset_index()
```

This should fix your issue.